# C# - way to get ACL/folder size from millions folders on network folder in 2023

Tags: c#, performance, acl

Sometimes i need to get ACL/folder (size...etc) info from million network folders (requests from auditors...etc)

With powershell - time needed is about 12 hours for 2.5kk folders

That is very slow

What should i use in C# to get that data faster (ideal - multithread). What classes, methods, etc?

Googled a lot - but only very old info found

Comment: Have you considered a simple client app that would run on a "regular"  (as small a time frame as you deem necessary) to pull folder sizes into a database and then query the database when needed?

Comment: The main problem is the speed of working with folders, not the storage of received data

Comment: I am looking at it from an angle of the solution, rather than fixing the apparent  problem. The problem is the amount of time it takes to run. But you could look at it with the perspective of having the data available when you need it and not actually having to wait for it, even when it takes 12 hours to run. Unless the sizes change drastically or your requirements are to have sizes within a small tolerance of current. Another idea would be to "push" the data from each client if you have control of the machines the folders reside on. That would make the process inherently "multi-threaded".

Comment: Another option would something pre-packaged like Agent Ransack (https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack). I have used this program for years and it is extremely fast and the results are exportable. The free version allows for up to 99 threads and 99 "indexing" threads (though full disclosure I have never needed to use more than the default 16 and 8). The Pro version will allow searching using a text file to determine which folders to find. Might be worth a look.